# Lua: Read Unsigned DWORD not working in Bizhawk Emulator

Tags: lua, emulation, unsigned, dword, gameboy

When I run my code I get an error on this line:

```
personality = memory.readdwordunsigned(0x02024744)
```

This is the error message I am given by the console:

```
LuaInterface.LuaScriptException: [string "main"]:26: attempt to call field 'readdwordunsigned' (a nil value)
```

I have been doing some testing and researching around this for a while and I cannot get it to work despite this concept being used on several other projects such as this: https://projectpokemon.org/forums/showthread.php?16681-Gen-3-Lua-Scripts

Some other information: 
1. I am running the lua script on the BizHawk emulator. 
2. if I change the line to memory.readbyte() I receive a different message, which leads me to believe that the console does not recognise memory.readdwordunsigned() as a funciton. 
3. The script is in the same folder as the executable file for the emulator.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Just read through http://tasvideos.org/Bizhawk/LuaFunctions.html quickly. No such function exists. Maybe it was made for an old version of the emulator. Looks like you should replace it with a call to one of the `memory.read_?` operations. I don't know enough about the platform to tell you the size or endianness of a dword.

Comment: Ah, I was worried that this would be the case. I'll try the functions on this page an do some more research in hopes of finding the answer. If I can't I might just download an old version of the emulator. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that support for memory.readdwordunsigned() is no longer supported in the BizHawk Emulator. After extensive research and help from a comment posted on my question I have managed to find a working alternative:
`memory.usememorydomain("System Bus")
personality=memory.read_u32_le(0x02024744)`

For anyone else who finds this answer useful, please note that a dword is unsigned and 4 bytes in size, hence the use of `u32`, because a dword is 32bits and unsigned. If you wanted to use a signed byte, for example, you would use `s8` instead. `le` means little endien, `be` can be used instead for big endien.

It is important to state the memory domain before attempting to read from memory because the memory domain I was using (IWRAM) as well as all other memory domains except for the system bus would produce this error due to the size of the memory address.

Comment: you could also simply use, memory.read_u32_le(0x02024744, "System Bus") which allows you to easily change between domains.